# How to delete previous symbol?

Tags: symbols

I want to remove all cites from document.

Document1:

```
.... 
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{}
\begin{document}
input{document2}
\end{document}
```

Document2:

```
\begin{document}
... bla-bla-bla \cite{Blablaer2012}. Foo bar bar fooed...
\end{document}
```

And I get

> bla-bla-bla .

How can I delete whitespace before? Maybe there is some command like \delprevsymbol?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command `\cite` accepts also an optional argument, so you should take care also of that one:

```
\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{\unskip\unpenalty}
```

should work. With `\unskip` you remove a preceding space, with `\unpenalty` also the penalty inserted when you write

```
text~\cite{foo}
```

(which is a recommended way).

There might be a problem if `\cite` is at the very start of a paragraph; a safer version might be

```
\renewcommand{\cite}[2][]{\ifhmode\unskip\unpenalty\fi}
```

Comment: +1 I especially like the `\ifhmode` refinement.